# Binomial dependent on a Poisson

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, poissons-equation

I have been working on a problem with a binomial rv dependent on a poisson rv and have worked through to this point:

$P(X=x) = \sum_{n=x}^{\infty} \dfrac{n!}{x!(n-x)!} p^x(1−p)^{n−x} \dfrac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!}$

Might someone guide me through a next step?

Comment: Some editing may be needed. If I am guessing correctly, the $X$ is the number of successes. The number $N$ of trials has a Poisson distribution. So the term at the end should be $\frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!}$. Maybe with that change you will be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Correct and yes - thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. It is good that the details were not then a problem. They are cleanly described by drhab.  There is also a more conceptual computation-free approach. If you look at the "axioms" that give rise to the Poisson, it is clear that $X$ satisfies these axioms, with probability of success in a time interval $(t,t+dt)$ roughly equal to $p\lambda\,dt$.

Comment: If you'd like to learn a lot of the tricks that, if you don't know them, seem like magic, grab [this book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0123814162?pc_redir=1405960488&robot_redir=1) from your library. (When I was in grad school, I wish I had earlier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a simple transformation: Let $j=n−x$. Then

$P(X=x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} p^x(1−p)^j \dfrac{\lambda^{x+j} e^{-\lambda}}{x!j!}$

And proceed. Hint: pull out the "x" terms. i remember similar from somewhere...

Comment: Pull out the x terms?

Comment: Yes, typographical error corrected, see penultimate line of drhab (with n-x = j).

Answer (score 1):

See the comment of André (at the end $\frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}$ instead of $\frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$).

Let $N,X_{1},X_{2},\dots$ be independent rv's with $N\sim$ Poisson$\left(\lambda\right)$
and $X_{i}\sim$ Bernouilli$\left(p\right)$.

Now define $X:=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{N}$.

Note that $X\sim$ Binom$\left(n,p\right)$ under condition $N=n$.
If $q:=1-p$ then:

$$P\left\{ X=x\right\} =\sum_{n=x}^{\infty}P\left\{ X=x\mid N=n\right\} P\left\{ N=n\right\} =\sum_{n=x}^{\infty}\binom{n}{x}p^{x}q^{n-x}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}=$$

$$e^{-\lambda}\frac{p^{x}\lambda^{x}}{x!}\sum_{n=x}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n-x}\lambda^{n-x}}{\left(n-x\right)!}=e^{-p\lambda}\frac{\left(p\lambda\right)^{x}}{x!}$$

(Last equality because: $\sum_{n=x}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n-x}\lambda^{n-x}}{\left(n-x\right)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n}\lambda^{n}}{n!}=e^{q\lambda}$)

So $X\sim$ Poisson$\left(\lambda p\right)$.

Comment: You are very welcome.